# Why is Asp.Net WebForms GridView performing an unasked DataBind() in OnPreRender()?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I'm working with a GridView in an UpdatePanel and perform databinding to an ObjectDataSource using the DataSourceID property. Everything works just fine except for when I perform data validation in the object source and return `false` from the Update. I use this to set the content and visibility of another control in the GridView. However, this never shows up since the GridView performs a hidden `DataBind()` in `OnPreRender()` even though `EnableViewState = "true"` (via the [BaseDataBoundControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.aspx)).

Is there an easy way to just turn this extraneous `DataBind()` off? I've used reflection to set the `_requiresDataBind` field in BaseDataBoundControl to `false` and all works as I'd like it to work, but this is hardly a production-worthy approach. Is subclassing GridView the only way? Am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no way around this if you don't databind the grid. I ended up subclassing the GridView, adding a Boolean property called "CancelDataBind", and overriding the method called EnsureDataBind() and adding logic to test the CancelDataBind property before calling the base implementation. This worked out well.